# postgresql - trying to group similar data within range criteria

Tags: postgresql

Hi – my sql skills are not the greatest but I’ve been assigned to a project that’s deep in the data.  Basically, I need to assign a group value to similar items based on multiple criteria.  I can do the matching of 2 columns fine, but the 3rd and 4th columns are only if the rows’ values fall into certain ranges of each other.

Example criteria

```
 1. Match Item Code on first 4 digits after leading zeros.
 2. Match Description based on first word only.
 3. Outlet Number, only group if value is +/- 200 of each other
 4. Cost, only group if value is within .75 of each other
```

The “Group” value should be like (this is totally made up data):

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEaiP.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEaiP.png)
if above link doesn't work, here's the text of data:

```
Item_Code   Description   Cat_Number Cost  Group
123401      HM Book Green   5000    15.50   1
0123402     HM Book Blue    5200    14.75   2
123403      HM Book Orange  5100    14.75   2
0123404     HM Book Red     4700    14.75   3
123405      HM Book Yellow  5200    14.50   2
798321      Car Light Bulb  4000    5.25    4
798322      Car Light Lens  4610    5.50    5
798330      Car Light fuse  4600    4.75    5
0074789     Pencil #2       9900    1.25    6
747889      Pencil          9800    0.99    6
747890      Pencil #1       9100    1.10    7
074788      Pencils         9345    1.99    8
074785      Pencil B        8000    1.50    9
```

This is what I have for the first 2 columns, which works well and it even appears to be working on the Cost column, but I can’t figure out how to group items on Cat Number (integer) too if within the 200 +/- range of each other – nothing I’ve tried is working:

```
    SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(item_code, '0'), 1, 4), 
         SPLIT_PART(description, ' ', 1), 
         cost::numeric(19,2),
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUBSTR(TRIM(item_code, '0'), 1, 4), 
         SPLIT_PART(description, ' ', 1), cost::numeric(19,2)) AS group_number
    FROM some_items
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(TRIM(item_code, '0'), 1, 4), 
            SPLIT_PART(description, ' ', 1),  
            (
               (cost = cost +.75), 
               (cost = cost -.75)
            ), cost
    ORDER BY item_code;
```

I’ve tried the same logic as I did on Cost, I’ve tried different combinations of common table expressions & joins, nested selects, a Having clause – but everything comes back to I want to somehow incorporate a range in the group by for Cat Number too.  It also may be a fluke that cost appears to be working – but so far it has been looking accurate.
I really appreciate any help or direction anyone can provide.
Thanks!!

Comment: If you save some example [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/), I will play with it!

Comment: yeah - I was wrong, the cost grouping isn't working either.  I've continued to dig into the data and was able to prove that doesn't work, which I didn't think it should.

(also, the above table is just sample, made up data to show my situation and the actual data could be 10s of thousands of rows.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick interest.
I tried to save a sample in my question, but it only saved a link to the image.  
Will try to save the text of data in my question. 
But I think my problem is focusing on Group By and I need to focus on Dense_Rank instead.

Comment: I wasn't successful saving my create table & insert script to the fiddle either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick! the groups I get, even if they don't have the same group id as the example, are composed of the same objects.

The resulting query is ugly and complex and I will bring it back to you at the end of this answer, but what is most interesting is the trick, in fact.

At the beginning, for semplicity, I will consider only the column `cat_number` (for the cost one is the same); after that, I will put all peaces together.

Let's go step by step!

```
 select item_code, description, cat_number, 
 cat_number - lag(cat_number,1,cat_number) over(order by cat_number) as le 
 from table1;
```

and we have this output:

```
| item_code | description    | cat_number | le   |
| --------- | -------------- | ---------- | ---- |
| 798321    | Car Light Bulb | 4000       | 0    |
| 798330    | Car Light fuse | 4600       | 600  |
| 798322    | Car Light Lens | 4610       | 10   |
| 123404    | HM Book Red    | 4700       | 90   |
| 123401    | HM Book Green  | 5000       | 300  |
| 123403    | HM Book Orange | 5100       | 100  |
| 123405    | HM Book Yellow | 5200       | 100  |
| 123402    | HM Book Blue   | 5200       | 0    |
| 74785     | Pencil B       | 8000       | 2800 |
| 747890    | Pencil #1      | 9100       | 1100 |
| 74788     | Pencils        | 9345       | 245  |
| 747889    | Pencil         | 9800       | 455  |
| 74789     | Pencil #2      | 9900       | 100  |
```

`le` contains the difference between the values of `cat_number` of each row respect to the previous one.

One more step:

```
select item_code
         , description
         , cat_number
         , case 
                when le >= 200 then cat_number 
                else null 
            end as lle from(
                    select item_code, description, cat_number, 
                    cat_number - lag(cat_number,1,cat_number) over(order by cat_number) as le 
                    from table1
            ) s1;

| item_code | description    | cat_number | lle  |
| --------- | -------------- | ---------- | ---- |
| 798321    | Car Light Bulb | 4000       |      |
| 798330    | Car Light fuse | 4600       | 4600 |
| 798322    | Car Light Lens | 4610       |      |
| 123404    | HM Book Red    | 4700       |      |
| 123401    | HM Book Green  | 5000       | 5000 |
| 123403    | HM Book Orange | 5100       |      |
| 123405    | HM Book Yellow | 5200       |      |
| 123402    | HM Book Blue   | 5200       |      |
| 74785     | Pencil B       | 8000       | 8000 |
| 747890    | Pencil #1      | 9100       | 9100 |
| 74788     | Pencils        | 9345       | 9345 |
| 747889    | Pencil         | 9800       | 9800 |
| 74789     | Pencil #2      | 9900       |      |
```

We have a value in `lle` only if, the corresponding value of `cat_number` does not fall within the same range as the previous columns.

One more step

```
    select item_code
             , description
             , cat_number
             , max(lle) over (order by cat_number) from (
                     select *
                     , case 
                            when le >= 200 then cat_number 
                            else null 
                        end as lle from(
                                select item_code, description, cat_number, 
                                cat_number - lag(cat_number,1,cat_number) over(order by cat_number) as le 
                                from table1
                        ) s1
               )s2;

| item_code | description    | cat_number | max  |
| --------- | -------------- | ---------- | ---- |
| 798321    | Car Light Bulb | 4000       |      |
| 798330    | Car Light fuse | 4600       | 4600 |
| 798322    | Car Light Lens | 4610       | 4600 |
| 123404    | HM Book Red    | 4700       | 4600 |
| 123401    | HM Book Green  | 5000       | 5000 |
| 123403    | HM Book Orange | 5100       | 5000 |
| 123405    | HM Book Yellow | 5200       | 5000 |
| 123402    | HM Book Blue   | 5200       | 5000 |
| 74785     | Pencil B       | 8000       | 8000 |
| 747890    | Pencil #1      | 9100       | 9100 |
| 74788     | Pencils        | 9345       | 9345 |
| 747889    | Pencil         | 9800       | 9800 |
| 74789     | Pencil #2      | 9900       | 9800 |
```

We filled empty values with the max value encountered  so far... and now we can use `dense_rank()` (as you had guessed)

```
    select item_code
             , description
             , cat_number
             , dense_rank() over (order by llle) from (
                             select *
                             , max(lle) over (order by cat_number) as llle from (
                                             select *
                                             , case 
                                                    when le >= 200 then cat_number 
                                                    else null 
                                                end as lle from(
                                                        select item_code, description, cat_number, 
                                                        cat_number - lag(cat_number,1,cat_number) over(order by cat_number) as le 
                                                        from table1
                                                ) s1
                               )s2
               )s3;

| item_code | description    | cat_number | dense_rank |
| --------- | -------------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 798330    | Car Light fuse | 4600       | 1          |
| 798322    | Car Light Lens | 4610       | 1          |
| 123404    | HM Book Red    | 4700       | 1          |
| 123405    | HM Book Yellow | 5200       | 2          |
| 123402    | HM Book Blue   | 5200       | 2          |
| 123401    | HM Book Green  | 5000       | 2          |
| 123403    | HM Book Orange | 5100       | 2          |
| 74785     | Pencil B       | 8000       | 3          |
| 747890    | Pencil #1      | 9100       | 4          |
| 74788     | Pencils        | 9345       | 5          |
| 74789     | Pencil #2      | 9900       | 6          |
| 747889    | Pencil         | 9800       | 6          |
| 798321    | Car Light Bulb | 4000       | 7          |
```

and we have in the same group only the values which `cat_number` is in the range specified!

And now put all in the same query!

```
 select item_code
             , description
             , cat_number
             , cost
             , dense_rank() over (
                        order by 
                            substring(item_code::text, 0, 4),
                            substring(description, 0, 4),
                            llle,
                            lllc) 
              from (
                 select *
                 , max(lle) over (order by cat_number) as llle
                 , max(llc) over (order by cost) lllc from (
                         select *
                         , case 
                                when le >= 200 then cat_number 
                                else null 
                            end as lle
                         , case
                               when lc >= 0.75 then cost
                                else null
                            end as llc
                           from(
                                    select item_code, description, cat_number,cost, 
                                    cat_number - lag(cat_number,1,cat_number) over(order by cat_number) as le,
                                    cost - lag(cost, 1, cost) over (order by cost) as lc
                                    from table1
                            ) s1
                    )s2
               )s3;

| item_code | description    | cat_number | cost  | dense_rank |
| --------- | -------------- | ---------- | ----- | ---------- |
| 123404    | HM Book Red    | 4700       | 14.75 | 1          |
| 123402    | HM Book Blue   | 5200       | 14.75 | 2          |
| 123405    | HM Book Yellow | 5200       | 14.50 | 2          |
| 123403    | HM Book Orange | 5100       | 14.75 | 2          |
| 123401    | HM Book Green  | 5000       | 15.50 | 3          |
| 74785     | Pencil B       | 8000       | 1.50  | 4          |
| 747890    | Pencil #1      | 9100       | 1.10  | 5          |
| 74788     | Pencils        | 9345       | 1.99  | 6          |
| 747889    | Pencil         | 9800       | 0.99  | 7          |
| 74789     | Pencil #2      | 9900       | 1.25  | 7          |
| 798322    | Car Light Lens | 4610       | 5.50  | 8          |
| 798330    | Car Light fuse | 4600       | 4.75  | 8          |
| 798321    | Car Light Bulb | 4000       | 5.25  | 9          |
```

P.s.: `item_code` do not have 0 at the beginning and I used a substring instead of your more correct expression, but the concept is the same.

Bye bye

Comment: Wow! I can't believe it & really can't wait to try it.  I've briefly read through it and it's nothing I could have come up with. I did not expect an answer over the weekend but thought I would take a peek this morning. I have somewhere I have to be now, but I'm definitely going to work on this today.It looks like you spent a great deal of time figuring this out, and I can't express enough how much I appreciate it.
Thank you so much for taking the all the time it must have took to solve this.
I will make another note after I've had a chance to work on it.
Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you, I'm sure it will be useful to you... it was for me. Good job!

Comment: This is absolutely **BRILLIANT**! I’ve been testing in my real-world scenario, making minor tweaks for my exact situation & it consistently produces the expected results. Your detailed step by step explanation really helped me understand the end query; although I did need to really break it down and execute each select from inner to out and really analyze the results to understand. It all still seems a bit magical to me – I didn’t even realize “lag(cost, 1, cost)” could be done.  None of the tutorials I saw explained this concept. I can’t thank you enough for your time and clever solution.  